# Using External "Table" Iibraries in SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, tabulator, suitescript2.0

I'm looking for some guidance in how to utilise a library such as [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) within a SuiteScript 2.0 SuiteLet Form.

The idea is to insert my JSON data into Tabulator, and let it do all the heavy lifting of displaying it.

However, I can't seem to get my head around how and where I define the library...

Tabulator uses a virtual DOM to render the table, and other functions to add/update data etc...

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell I do this for an embedded react app where the react app is defined normally and packaged by webpack. This one is a whole page app so no client side interaction with Netsuite. For client side interaction I just communicate between Netsuite and my embedded apps with event handlers where the Netsuite side of the event handlers are included in a client script added with Form.clientScriptModulePath

```
var form = ui.createForm({
    title:'Embedded App'
});

//form.clientScriptModulePath = './netsuite-handler.js'; // if needed to interact between Netsuite UI widget fields and your app


var wrapper = form.addField({
    id:'custpage_wrapper',
    type:ui.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
    label:'na/'
});

var scriptFileName = 'some-likely-unique-script-name.js';
var scriptURL = getFileURL(scriptFileName); // search files by name; return url from search

var cssFileName = 'some-likely-unique-script-name.css';
var styleURL = getFileURL(cssFileName);


wrapper.defaultValue = '<div id="app_wrap"><div id="app_root"></div>\n'+
    '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ styleURL +'"/>\n'+
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="'+scriptURL +'"></script>'+
    '</div>';

context.response.writePage(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage AMD modules in suitescript. Then you could use a client script to initialize your library on netsuite forms, suitelets etc.